# Problems with gpu rendering

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics, window, browser, gpu

Problems with gpu rendering.
A game (forgeofempires.com) has some visual errors.

Background image gets random black lines/pixels.
screenshot: https://ibb.co/P15z4t1

Text disappears/gets unreadable/tangled
screenshot: https://ibb.co/jH1PMHX

Pages(parts) disappear, not visible, but html elements are there can bee seen "tips" if I hoover over mouse.
screenshots:
https://ibb.co/tMHwGJF
https://ibb.co/5MGG4z1
https://ibb.co/4SSvNfr

Reloading the page(game) works for a little time. But these errors will come up again for sure.

The thing is If I would know the actual locations of the html elements, could click them and it would work. The problem is with displaying them - I can't see them.

VGA card:
sudo lspci  -v -s  $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1)

> ```
> 02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV530 [Radeon X1600 PRO] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
>         Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RV530 [Radeon X1600 PRO]
>         Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31, NUMA node 0
>         Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
>         Memory at fbbe0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
>         I/O ports at c000 [size=256]
>         Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
>         Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
>         Capabilities: [58] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
>         Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
>         Kernel driver in use: radeon
>         Kernel modules: radeon
> ```

It's an old ATI vga card.

lsb_release -a

> ```
> No LSB modules are available.
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
> Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
> Release:        20.04
> Codename:       focal
> ```

Desktop environment is LXQT/openbox.

Chromium GPU report: [chrome://gpu/](https://pastebin.com/0MUwGEck)

Chromium is latest snap version (88.0.4324.96).

VGA driver is latest ppa oibaf driver ([https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers))

If hardware acceleration is disabled the game is painfully slow, takes minutes to open menu items.

I'm ex windows user - used it for many years. Learned some linux basics at school years ago, and now finally convinced myself to use linux on every day basis. So I can say I'm inexperienced newbie.

Please help me solve this issue. I'm open to any suggestipn.
Maybe If somehow gpu could be forced to redraw the screen could help? But how can I do it?
Or maybe vga driver should be replaced?
Any advice is welcome!